# Making this code work on boot

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, boot

I have been stuck on this for weeks now...I can not get this to work. What I am trying to do is for my app to recognize when a user plugs in there earphones/headphones into the phone, and when they do, for it to show a notification icon. Here is my class. I have added the

```
 public class ItudeMobileBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1234567890;
     NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

     @Override 
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         /* Only perform this code if the BroadcastReceiver received the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED action.*/
         Log.d("Autobooted", "it booted");
         Toast laToast = Toast.makeText(context, "I have booted", 5);
         laToast.show();
         //It boots so it shows that toast. Rest doesn't work though    
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
             int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
             switch (state) {
             case 0:
                 Log.d("unplugged", "Headset was unplugged");
                 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                 notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
                 Toast unpluggedToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Headset has been disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 unpluggedToast.show();
                 break;
             case 1:
                 Log.d("plugged", "Headset is plugged");
                 mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                 showNotification(context, R.drawable.notification_icon, "short", false);
                 Toast pluggedToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Headset has been connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 pluggedToast.show();
                 break;
             default:
                 Log.d("uh", "I have no idea what the headset state is");
                 Toast defaultToast = Toast.makeText(context, "No headset detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 defaultToast.show();
             }
         }
     }

     private void showNotification(Context context, int statusBarIconID, String string, boolean showIconOnly) {
         Intent contentIntent = new Intent();
         //Text that it says in the notification area when the notification appears
         String dropDownText = "Notification Title";
         Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, "Notification Title", System.currentTimeMillis());
         n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); //Activity that will be launched if notification is clicked
         PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
         n.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Notification Title", "Bottom Line", pending);
         mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
     }
 }
```

And here is my manifest

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.testreciever"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <receiver android:name="com.example.testreciever.BootCompletedReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver 
                android:enabled="true"
                android:name=".ItudeMobileBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.testreciever.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.testreciever.Hope"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_hope" >
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

On boot it does show the "it booted" toast, so I know it's working. But it's not showing the notification icon when I plug in the earphones. I really just don't know what to do anymore. If you can help, please do. Thank You so much.

I know the notification code works, because if i put it in an activity class and i launch the app it works, but I don't want to have to launch the app. I just want it to work on boot.

Comment: You could have spent the weeks taking the advice given to you before.  **Learn how to use the debugger**.  if you did this, you could examine the intent, see what extras it has, step through your code and see **exactly** what it's doing and why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HeadsetObserver](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/com/android/server/HeadsetObserver.java#HeadsetObserver) class is responsible for broadcasting `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` when a headset in plugged in/out. Here's some of the code from `HeadsetObserver.sendIntent()`

```
        //  Pack up the values and broadcast them to everyone
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
        int state = 0;
        int microphone = 0;

        if ((headset & HEADSETS_WITH_MIC) != 0) {
            microphone = 1;
        }
        if ((headsetState & headset) != 0) {
            state = 1;
        }
        intent.putExtra("state", state);
        intent.putExtra("name", headsetName);
        intent.putExtra("microphone", microphone);

        if (LOG) Slog.v(TAG, "Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG: state: "+state+" name: "+headsetName+" mic: "+microphone);
        // TODO: Should we require a permission?
        ActivityManagerNative.broadcastStickyIntent(intent, null);
```

As you can see, the intent is flagged with [Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY). This means that the broadcast cannot be received by a `BroadcastReceiver` defined in your AndroidManifest.xml.

You have to have some component of you app running, ie. a `Service` or an `Activity`, and register the receiver with `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)`

**Edit, example code**

As I said, you need to have some component of your app running, to receive the `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` broadcast. The best option is probably a `Service`.

So lets create a `Service`, HeadsetObserverService.java:

```
public class HeadsetObserverService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "HeadsetObserverService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // Create a filter. We are interested in the Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG action
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);

        // Register a new HeadsetReceiver
        registerReceiver(new HeadsetReceiver(), filter);

        // We return START_STICKY. If our service gets destroyed, Android will try to restart it when resources are available.      
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class HeadsetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
                switch (state) {
                case 0:
                     Log.d("unplugged", "Headset was unplugged");

                     // Cancel notification here

                break;
                case 1:
                     Log.d("plugged", "Headset is plugged");

                     // Show notification

                break;
                default:
                    Log.w("uh", "I have no idea what the headset state is");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want this `Service` to be started automatically when the phone reboots, you'll need a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for the `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive() - Received broadcast");

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive() - Intent action: " + Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive() - Starting service..");

            // Phone is booted, lets start the service
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, HeadsetObserverService.class);           
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add the new `Service` and the `BootReceiver` to your AndroidManifest

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".HeadsetObserverService">
```

You should also have an `Activity` where the user can start and stop the `HeadsetObserverService`

Comment: Well what I did was add     `Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);` to the code right after the autobooted log. And now it sort of reads it, but when you turn it on it says no headset connected by default, even if one is connected

Comment: @FernandoRamirez Why are you creating a new `Intent`? I don't think you understood my answer. I'll update my answer with some examples in a couple of minutes

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to figure it out with this. Don't think you know how much this means to me, thanks a lot again! @Ole