# How to respond once to multiple broadcasts? Jelly Bean LG sending two broadcasts for one event

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm using some working code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621860/making-this-code-work-on-boot?answertab=active#tab-top) within a service for detecting headphone connection state via ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.  I have two phones for testing, a Gingerbread Motorola and a Jelly Bean LG.  On the Gingerbread phone everything works fine...i plug in headphones and I get one broadcast from Android and then I execute my work.  On the Jelly Bean phone I'm getting two(2) broadcasts for every headphone state change and consequently my own stuff is then called twice.  I'm not 100% certain but I don't think this is related to sticky broadcasts as if that were the case I should see the same behavior on both Gingerbread and Jellybean phones.

Filtering all system logcat msgs for "headset_plug" on the Jelly Bean phone I'll see something like this on a headset state change:

```
02-01 07:39:11.983: I/MusicBrowser(1739): [MediaPlaybackService.java:mHeadsetReceiver.onReady()] oooooo intentIntent { act=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG flg=0x40000010 (has extras) }
02-01 07:39:12.083: I/MusicBrowser(1739): [MediaPlaybackService.java:mHeadsetReceiver.onReady()] oooooo intentIntent { act=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG flg=0x40000010 (has extras) }
```

I could be mistaken but everything seems like this phone is sending two broadcasts within microseconds of each other whereas the Gingerbread Motorola is only sending one.  I don't know if this is an Android bug, an intentional change between versions, an issue with this specific LG phone or what but it seems I need a way to respond only one time when the same broadcast is sent out multiple times.

Comment: Have you examined the extras on those `Intents`, to see if there are differences?

Comment: My assumption is the extras are identical because the results are identical.  In the linked code above it filters for the "state" extra in a switch statement and logs plugged(state 1) and unplugged(state 0).  On the Jelly Bean phone I always get exactly two plugged or two unplugged log messages.  If the extras were different I should get two different logs or ignore the extras if they didn't match the "state" type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes later w/ the same problem...

I couldn't figure out how to deal with multiple broadcasts using boolean values for the state but I did solve this by setting an integer for the state.  If the service receives multiple broadcasts for "unplugged" it will always set the int lastHeadsetState to 0.  If it receives multiple broadcasts for plugged the first broadcast will set lastHeadsetState to 1 and additional broadcasts will increment lastHeadsetState by 1.  I then check if lastHeadsetState equals exactly 1 and then do my work.  Any value other than 1 implies multiple broadcasts were received and should be ignored.

So here's my code for service that listens for headphone plug/unplug state changes, ignores the initial sticky broadcasts generated when the service is launched and contains logic to tolerate multiple broadcasts from wacky hardware.  If anyone cares to suggest a more elegant way to achieve the same result I'd be interested.  Apologies for any formatting errors below:

```
public class HeadsetService extends Service{

private static final String TAG = "HeadsetService";
private HeadsetReceiver hReceiver;
private int lastHeadsetState;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();       
    hReceiver = new HeadsetReceiver();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Register a new HeadsetReceiver       
    IntentFilter hfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);    
    registerReceiver(hReceiver, hfilter);

return START_STICKY;}

 private class HeadsetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {

        // ignore the initial sticky broadcast when the service starts
        if (isInitialStickyBroadcast()) {
        } 

        else { 

        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch (state) {
        case 0:             
            Log.d(TAG, "headset unplugged");
            //set lastHeadsetState to 0 for later comparison
        lastHeadsetState = 0;               
            Log.d(TAG, "lastHeadsetState set to 0");

        break;
        case 1:                             
            Log.d(TAG, "headset plugged in!");
            lastHeadsetState = (lastHeadsetState + 1);
            Log.d(TAG, "lastHeadsetState incremented by 1");
            //check if lastHeadsetState is exactly 1...any greater value means multiple broadcasts were received.
            if (lastHeadsetState == 1) {
        //do whatever you're going to do when the headset is plugged in here                   

        Log.d(TAG, "Headset state has changed from unplugged to plugged");
            }
             else 
                 Log.d(TAG, "Multiple broadcasts received, ignoring duplicates");

        break; 
        default:
            Log.w("uh", "I have no idea what the headset state is");
            }   
          }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way to respond only one time when the same broadcast is sent out multiple times

If you receive two, three, or a million broadcasts in succession, where the `state` value has not changed from the previous broadcast, the state has not changed. Only perform your "the state has changed" logic when `state` changes, not just because you received the broadcast.

Whether you need a dedicated `boolean lastHeadsetState` data member to detect the change in state, or can infer the last state from other things in your app, I cannot say.

Now, ideally, you would not need this logic, as ideally the broadcast would only go out once, upon a change in state. The closer you get to hardware, the more device quirks pop up. Hence, the [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) is all the more important the closer you get to hardware.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I'll read up on modifying that broadcast receiver to work only on state changes instead of individual broadcasts and post it here if I get something working.  I guess I was just thrown a bit because everyone points to some variation of that code here whenever the topic of headset detection comes up yet I couldn't find anyone asking what to do in the case of  multiple identical broadcasts.  If it is model specific I wonder what LG would have done to the Android image to trigger multiple broadcasts.

Comment: @CharlieNS: "If it is model specific I wonder what LG would have done to the Android image to trigger multiple broadcasts" -- screwed up, probably. If you think this is messy, try working with the camera sometime... :-)

Comment: Thanks again for your advice.  It put me on the right path to a solution I added to my initial question.